# How can I use the Outlook REST API to get messages that have recently changed IsRead state?

Tags: outlook-restapi

I've been using the Outlook REST API but can't figure out how to detect IsRead changes on messages. API is here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#all-mail-api-operations

It seems like if I use the Synchronize or GetMessages APIs then changing the IsRead value on a message doesn't affect the LastModifiedDateTime of the message and so the message doesn't show up when trying to get recently changed messages (either using Synchronize or Getting messages that have a recent LastModifiedDateTime).

What is the correct way to detect messages that have recently changed their IsRead value but no other properties have?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to subscribe to notifications on the mailfoder, you should get notifications for the read status change.